# Why is my Custom Message being sent when the application starts up?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I have my application set up with a worker thread, and I'm using `PostMessage()` with a custom message `WM_THREAD_FINISHED` to notify the main thread that it has finished execution. I'm handling the custom message in a method `OnThreadFinish()`. It appears that this method is called as the application is starting up, which is causing me problems. I'm getting a crash which I think is due to there being no data in `a, b, or c`. Is there any reason why the message should be called on the application's initialisation?

```
#define WM_THREAD_HAS_FINISHED WM_USER +0

struct DataItem {
    int a;
    int b;
    double c;
};

....
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CProject1Dlg, CDialogEx)
    ....
    ....
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_THREAD_HAS_FINISHED, &CProject1Dlg::OnThreadFinish)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
....

UINT WorkThread( LPVOID pParam) {

    // Do stuff

    DataItem* m_CurrentData;
    m_CurrentData->a = a;
    m_CurrentData->b = b;
    m_CurrentData->c = c;

    // End thread, notify main thread of completion
    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_THREAD_HAS_FINISHED, (WPARAM) m_CurrentData, 0);
    AfxEndThread(0);

    return 0;
    } 



LRESULT CProject1Dlg::OnThreadFinish(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    // Retrieve data from thread
    std::auto_ptr<DataItem> currentData(reinterpret_cast<DataItem*>(wParam));

    int a = currentData.a;
    int b = currentData.b;
    double c = currentData.c;

    // Do stuff

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

```
#define WM_THREAD_HAS_FINISHED (WM_APP+0)
```

`WM_USER+X` is the range reserved for the specific window class, not the application. So you can only define this range if you are creating a new Window class

It seems that you are using a Dialog, that is a standard, although undocumented, window class. So your particular message collides with this one, copied from `winuser.h`:

```
#define DM_GETDEFID (WM_USER+0)
```

And as you can easily check, this message is sent a lot.

Anyway, if you want to play on the safe side, you can also use `RegisterWindowMessage()`.

Comment: Nice answer.  Additional explanation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/10/24/10362204.aspx